# Trying to remove exisitng parameters in Crystal Report 10 report by creating new subreport to provide the parameter data

Tags: crystal-reports

Hello:  I am trying to run crystal report 10 report from command line (and I'm new to crystal).  The report has two date parameters ?from and ?to.  I can query a different database to get the ?from and ?to parameters.  So what I'm trying to do is get rid of the external parameters by generating the dates from within the report to replace/populate ?from and ?to.

Can I somehow add a sub-report to query Oracle to get the ?to and ?from dates?  This new sub-report would need to run first since the other four reports (3 subs and 1 main report hitting SQL server) all use these date parameters?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

To the extent I know, Whether you use sub report of main report if a user needs to enter his own parameters to query the database then you need to create external parameters

Edit------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Since you are trying to get the date input from different database... your approach is correct to create a sub report for this.

1. Make sure to place the sub report first in order from where you are taking the values.
2. Either use a shared variable or through parameter linking get the date values to main report and pass the values to remaining sub reports through `linking` option in sub report links.

Comment: Thanks for the response.<br> "if a user needs to enter his own parameters to query the database" - well, that is what I'm trying to eliminate.  I have report that calls for two date parameters, but I can get the two dates from a different database.  I want to create another query/subreport to get those two dates thus eliminating the need for parameters.